# Doctrine JoinColumn id is Null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm stuck with my relation.

Here's my entity :

```
class Orderproduct 
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="orderproduct", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\Machining", mappedBy="orderproduct", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $machining;
```

And my two others entity :

```
class Product
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\Orderproduct", inversedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="orderproduct_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $orderproduct;

class Machining
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\Orderproduct", inversedBy="machining")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="orderproduct_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $orderproduct;
```

And I've got this error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'orderproduct_id' ne peut être vide (null)
```

Here's my simple add function

```
public function addOrderproductAction(Request $request)
    {
        $orderproduct = new Orderproduct();

        $formorderproduct = $this->createForm(OrderproductType::class, $orderproduct);


        if($formorderproduct->handleRequest($request)->isValid())
        {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($orderproduct);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('product_bundle_listorderproduct'));
        }


        return $this->render('ProductBundle:Default:neworderproduct.html.twig', array(
            'formorderproduct' => $formorderproduct->createView(),
        ));

    }
```

And i got this with a dump just before the flush :[image]

Any idea ?

Thx for your help!

Edit : After put $product->getOrderproduct($this) and $machining->getOrderproduct($this). 
[image]

**Edit :**

I'm changing my model but still have the same problem. So I have a relation between product and machining

**Product**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\Machining", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $machining;
```

**Machining**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="machining")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $product;
```

This is Machining table in my Db : product_id is null.
[image]

I already try to modify setProduct in Machining but it still the same.

Comment: Try to persist all entity before flushing. Sometimes it is required to flush the related entity first...so it will have id (cascade persist could solve that)

Comment: I've try this `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($orderproduct);
            $em->flush(); `

Comment: also without the code it's pretty hard to debug it...at least copy the part where you set the relation, persist and flush

Comment: I edit my post. But I was thinking it was "just" an ORM problem.

Comment: it seems that the related entites does not know about your orderproduct. try to set it "from the other side"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in Orderproduct' addMachining($machining) method:

```
$this->machining[] = $machining;
$machining->setOrderproduct($this);
return $this;
```

the same for the other entity(of course different method name and properties). If this does not work try to persist all entity separately.

Comment: It's not automatically with a cascade persist ?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution :

In the buildForm simply add

```
'by_reference => false'
```

Now it's work !